# Who were the members of the jury in the Game of Thrones finale?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the *Game of Thrones* Season 8 finale, in the trial of

> Tyrion Lannister

I could recognize:

> 1. Samwell Tarly
>  2. Edmure Tully
>  3. Davos Seaworth
>  4. Arya Stark
>  5. Sansa Stark
>  6. Bran Stark
>  7. Yara Greyjoy
>  8. Yohn Royce

Who are the others?

Comment: One is mentioned as the uncle of Sansa, but I don't think he is ever named. I presume the others were meant to be just like him: lords of the 7 kingdoms whose names aren't actually important.

Comment: Edmure Tully is the uncle of Sansa Stark

Comment: Were they a jury?

Answer (score 28):

[image: Tyrion's jury members 1 - 7]

1. Ser Brienne of Tarth
2. Ser Davos Seaworth
3. Lord Gendry Baratheon
4. Lord Une according to the GoT wiki but the claim is unsourced so take that with a pinch of salt. In fact I'm pretty sure there is no House Une in the books or show mentioned before this point.
5. Unknown
6. Yara Greyjoy
7. Prince of Dorne (unnamed)

[image: Tyrion's jury members 8 - 10]

8. Samwell Tarly
9. Unknown
10. Lord Edmure Tully

[image: Tyrion's jury members 11 - 13]

11. Arya Stark
12. Bran Stark
13. Sansa Stark

[image: Tyrion's jury members 14 - 16]

14. Robin Arryn
15. Yohn Royce
16. Unknown

Comment: +1 for adding numbered pictures. I will accept it once blanks are filled. :)

Comment: @HBhatia I don't recognise the blank characters so I think they might be unnamed but I'll have a look.

Comment: #5 is likely some Northman, given his clothing and all...?

Comment: @JNat Same with 16 but I think they're just Red Shirts.

Comment: Most certainly, @TheLethalCarrot: though them looking like Northmen makes sense, given the overwhelming approval of a Stark for king; pretty much everyone there has some sort of allegiance to the North (the Prince of Dorne and Yara excluded, I guess).

Comment: Isn't the Prince of Dorne named Trystane?

Comment: @KevinMilner He was until Obara Sand kills him in Season 6.

Comment: Someone on [Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/game-of-thrones-characters-on-council-that-made-bran-king-series-finale-2019-5) wondered the same thing.  #4 is listed as Lord Une, presumably of somewhere in the Stormlands.  #5 is an unnamed northern lord, possibly of House Karstark, Umber, Reed, Forrester, or Glover.  #9 is an unnamed lord from either the Reach or the Westerlands (previously belonging to House Lannister).  #16 is an unnamed eastern lord loyal to House Arryn and the Eyrie.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I've watched the series 2 times in a row now and I honestly don't remember him getting killed. I do remember him just kind of disappearing though...

Comment: @KevinMilner He's definitely executed (in a play by the Sand Snakes, as I recall), though I believe his actual death is off-camera. It was handled in the tradition of the entire Dornish plotline: poorly and sloppily.

Comment: @KevinMilner he gets spiked through the head. It’s pretty clear.

Comment: @Upper_Case He dies [quite clearly on camera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcSF0JayMZg), a pretty gruesome death too.

Answer (score 8):

Found one person

> [image: Robyn Arryn of Eyrie]

It turns out that

> He is Robin Arryn of Vale.

Comment: I thought it was interesting how much healthier he looked - I always suspected Littlefinger had arranged for someone to slip him some low-dose poison to keep him weak while he was plotting to use Lysa to take the Vale...

Comment: @user568458 I always figured that was more from his mom never letting him leave the house.